# excluding Factory RecreatableObjectFacetFactory and adding my own Factory in isis.properties

Tags: isis

I have written a View Model Facet Factory that is supposed to replace

> RecreatableObjectFacetFactory

I have excluded RecreatableObjectFacetFactory and added my own factory in isis.properties but keep on getting the following error when the meta model validates :

> domainapp.modules.system.vm.impl.FileVM: has multiple incompatible annotations/interfaces indicating that it is a recreatable object of some sort (SystemViewModelFacetObjectInterface and RecreatableObjectFacetForRecreatableObjectInterface)

I think I understand what the error is telling me, nl that there are 2 view model facets interfaces defined for the ViewModel interface. The problem I have is that RecreatableObjectFacetForRecreatableObjectInterface is registered as far as I can see by RecreatableObjectFacetFactory and this should have been excluded as per isis.properties. I am using isis 1.15.1

My questions are :

1. Does exclude work properly in 1.15.1?
2. How can I make sure that RecreatableObjectFacetForRecreatableObjectInterface does not get registered by the framework during startup?

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this, unfortunately it does seem to be broken.  I've raised a ticket [ISIS-1780](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ISIS-1780) to fix in the next release.